# How gamma rays are produced?

Tags: atomic-physics, radiation

Radio active materials emit alpha beta and gamma rays. My question is, what causes (at subatomic level) an atom to produce such a powerful gamma rays and Suppose if I bring a fluorescent bulbs nearby strong gamma radiation, does it glow bulb?

Comment: Hi VivekRajendran and welcome to Physics.SE! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: "Always emit alpha beta and gamma rays"? No, definitely not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a nucleus decays, there is usually excess energy (binding energy of the nucleons) liberated, and this energy is carried away by any of the "fragments" - daughter nuclei, emitted particles (alpha, beta, gamma, neutrino, ...).

The amount of energy involved can be quite large (think atom bomb), so when the energy liberated is released in the form of electromagnetic wave, it packs a punch. The gamma ray.

The penetrating power of the gamma ray relates to its energy: the probability of interaction with an electron goes down as the energy goes up (up to a point), and even after interacting, it tends to continue "more or less in the same direction" as described by the Compton and Klein-Nishina equations.

And yes, a fluorescent bulb contains a scintillating (phosphor) material on the inside, and this material will glow slightly in the presence of gamma rays. However, I would recommend you don't stand close enough to a source capable of producing this effect as visible light - you would get a serious radiation dose.

I did once take a powerful source of 356 keV photons (10 mCi of Ba-133) and put it below a 3" NaI scintillator in a dark room. It took several minutes for my eyes to accommodate and see a faint glow. Since the phosphor in a light bulb is very thin, you would need a much more powerful source to see anything - especially if you don't go into a dark room.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I'm aware this answer needs some work**:
Whilst I'm sure there will be a plethora of much more detailed answers I'll give a simple answer to question one. This is more about internally understanding how the process works than an extremely accurate description. Gamma ray is an electromagnetic wave. Basically we have a set of forces called electromagnetic forces. These forces are caused by different charged particles interacting with another at distance. This interaction operates through something called the electromagnetic field which for our purposes will be composed of an electric field and a magnetic field. It's basically something that has a defined vector (read: set of numbers usually related to direction and magnitude of one or more things/forces/velocities etc.) at every point in space. Looking at this simply, a charged electron produces a spike in the 'charge field' where it is that slowly dissipates outwards. Now changes in the field move at the speed of light. If I was to instantly vaporise the electron (hypothetically) then for a short time the field around the electron (not directly at the point where the electron was but around it) would retain its original value before a 'wave' originating from the point in the field where the electron was travels out saying 'hey, there's no charge there anymore'. If make an electron appear at point A then a 'wave' will travel out indicating the new presence of charge. If I move the electron 'up' by 1m (I'm just saying up for reference there's no really orientation system in our imaginary empty universe) to B then a 'wave' will travel out as the charge moves 'up' by 1m. Because of the way electric and magnetic forces interact, this wave rippling out in the electric field causes a magnetic wave to be created at a 90 degree angle which then causes an electric wave at a 90 degree angle etc thus a self sustaining electromagnetic wave. And so roughly you can see how an electron moving can start an electromagnetic wave in the following rough diagram:

[image: Very poorly drawn diagram]

I'll attempt to fix the diagram later but I hope it helps you to understand. So when energy is applied to an atom, an electron in one of the outer orbits (I'm assuming atom structure is known) moves up to a higher energy orbit - it moves further away from the nucleus it is attracted to which requires energy. When it wants to come back down it releases its energy is the form of this electromagnetic wave as we've discussed through this jump.